# AJAX Asynchronous Callback Function - what is the parameter/argument passed in?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

I have an asynchronous ajax function, complete with a callback:

```
var coreChat = {

      fetch: function (fn) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          data: {
             order: 'createdAt',
             limit: 10
          },
          type: "GET"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          var messages = [];
          for (var i = 0, len = data.results.length; i < len; i++) {
            messages.push(data.results[i].text);
          }

          return fn(messages);
        });
      },
```

I'm pretty sure the `.done(function(data) {...` portion of the above code is the callback, though feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Now I'm getting confused when this `fetch` asynchronous function is called later on in the code...

```
    var myChat = {

    updateMessages: function () {
        this.fetch(function (messages) {
          myChat.display(messages);
        });
      }

    };

    $.extend(myChat, coreChat);
    myChat.init();
```

In the updateMessages function, `fetch` is called with a parameter, which is another function - my question is - is that function the new callback? Does it replace the callback that was originally defined in the `fetch` function? Or maybe it's the argument to the callback that's originally called in the fetch function? I'm a bit lost here and any help would be appreciated...

If you'd like a link to the entire code:

[all the code](https://github.com/joaostein/chatBuilder/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: No; it's just a function that your (inner) callback calls.  Callbacks are not magic; they're just regular functions that you can call whenever you like.

Comment: so it's a callback to the callback? @SLaks